# Can constructors be private?

Tags: delphi, constructor

Is there any reason why constructors in object pascal can not be private?

Comment: Constructors aren't private in C++, either: `struct Foo { Foo() = default; };`

Comment: you do not understand, @KerrekSB, have you tried to do a singleton in delphi/pascal? In c++ you can change constructor's visibility to private but in delphi that's not possible.

Comment: Ah OK Maybe [this is relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392107/delphi-singleton-pattern)?

Comment: @KerrekSB, look a singleton pattern in this link you'll see the visibility of constructor as private: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern

Comment: Why can't you declare your constructor private?

Comment: offcourse is relevant in delphi we should use tricks to have a singleton, because i can alwasys call the public constructor, thats goes against the standard used by many languages

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14003208/243614

Comment: To have a private constructor, you have to use a trick that declares a private constructor! ???

Comment: @WellingtonSilvaRibeiro, not so, see the duplicate, more specifically Uwe's answer.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, LOL missed that, thanks that's actually funny. :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB: unlike C++, Delphi has a rooted class system, and constructors are inherited. So even hiding a constructor as private will still surface the root class's constructor, TObject.Create. That can not be properly hidden.