# Is there a way to "code reuse" classes that are only exposed the implementation section?

Tags: delphi, inheritance

I've just read an interesting approach of structuring code that hides the actual classes deep in the implementation section of the units and exposes them only with interfaces as seen below:

```
unit MyClass;

interface

type

   IMyClass = interface(IInterface)
   [GUID]
      procedure A;
      procedure B;
   end;

function CreateMyClass: IMyClass;

implementation

type

   TMyClass = class(TInterfaceObject, IMyClass)
   strict private    
      procedure A;
      procedure B;
   end;

function CreateMyClass: IMyClass;
begin
   Result := TMyClass.Create;
end;

   ...

end;
```

This works wonders until I need to inherit a class from TMyClass for code reusing. Is there a way to do that besides inserting the second class in the same unit `implementation` section?

Comment: The class itself isn't visible anywhere else except within that unit, below where it's declared. How would you expect to do it any differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that you can inherit from a class is in code that can see the declaration of the class. Ergo, if the declaration appears only in an implementation section, only code that is also in that implementation section can derive from that class.

Comment: So, in Delphi there is no way to hide constructor methods and, at the same time, inherit this hidden class from another unit?

Comment: You can make the constructor private.

Comment: But this way can't override TObject public constructor

Comment: That statement doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: I mean, if I make the class constructor private, I still can call it with TObject public "Create" constructor

Comment: You can hide it though. If you wish. I think I answered the question you asked.

Comment: Ok, sorry to bother you, David. I'll accept your answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003153/how-to-hide-the-inherited-tobject-constructor-while-the-class-has-overloaded-one

Comment: Yes, I read that post before asking my question here. "Andy Hausladen's trick" is good if you want to hide TObject Create and force client classes to use your class specific constructor. Although, if you want to completely hide all the constructors (your class constructor + TObject class constructor) you can't do that in Delphi unfortunately.